# Can getConnection method recognize old connection and delete them?

Tags: java, database, url

If we had an instance of Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (url) and call the getConnection method again with some other url, ie some url to another database, such as con = DriverManager.getConnection (secondUrl) do you need to close the previous one established connection or method "recognizes" that an established connection already exists and closes it itself?

Answer (score 0):

DriverManager.getConnection() asks a new connection from the driver. It has no special knowledge of any other connections so it does not recognize anything. You can see all it does by looking [at the source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#L632-L690). It's not much.

It would not make sense for it to close the previous connection. How would it know you're not using it anymore? It is perfectly valid to have several connections to a database active. That's what connection pools are meant for.

As an app programmer, one should also note that DriverManager is not used that much anymore for database connections, and its use is discouraged. Connection pooling and [Datasources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) are.